# Adding generic constraints at runtime?

Tags: c#, generics, constraints

I'm pretty stumped with this so if anyone has any ideas.  I have the generic method

```
public void Foo<TClass>(TClass item) where TClass : class
{ }
```

And I want to call this method from another generic method, but this generic method doesn't have the type constraint "where TClass : class"

```
public void Bar<T>(T item)
{
    this.Foo<T>(item);
}
```

This doesn't work, I get the error

*"The type 'T' must be a reference type in order to use it as parameter 'TClass'"*

Which I understand.  But my question is this - is there anything I can do with C# syntax in order to "filter" the generic type "T" to pass it to "this.Bar" if it is a class.  Something like....

```
public void Bar<T>(T item)
{
    if (typeof(T).IsClass)
        this.Foo<T **as class**>();
}
```

I realise I could use reflection to call Foo, but this just seems like cheating.  Is there something I can do with C# to pass "T" on with the constraint at runtime?

Also - I can't change the constraint on the method "Bar" as it comes from an interface so the constraint has to match the constraint on the interface

Comment: Did you mean "this.Foo<T **as class**>();" ?

Comment: well spotted - edited :)

Comment: So why don't you use `if (typeof (T).IsClass)` ??

Comment: because the compiler won't read that logic, so I will still get a compile error when doing this.Foo<T>(item)

Comment: @horrorcat ah,sorry now I understand you,it seems you need reflection, in your words _cheating_ :)

Comment: hahaha! yeah - it is cheating! :-P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way to call `Foo` without reflection, is to cast `item` to one of the types/classes in its hierarchy (after the proper `IsClass` check).

Obviously, there's only one type in its hierarchy that you know of *a priori*: `Object`.

```
public void Bar<T>(T item)
{
    if (typeof(T).IsClass)
        this.Foo((object) item);
}
```

Edit :

Also, in one of the comments you said you added the `class` constraint to be to instantiate `T`. You don't need that, what you need is the [`new` constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sd2w2ew5.aspx).

Comment: Wow that actually compiles, I totally forgot you could "shortcut" generics like that cheers! Also yeah you're right, I did actually the new constraint as well but left it out of this question to simplify it :)

Comment: While this solution is good for some cases, notice that calling Foo<object>(item) is not always equivalent to calling Foo<T>(item).

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately there is no way to do this without changing `Bar` to have the generic constraint `class` or using reflection.  In order to compile C# must know at compile time that `T` is indeed a `class` value.  There is no way to use a dynamic test such as `typeof(T).IsClass` in order to satisfy this compile time constraint.

You mentioned in the question that you can't change `Bar` but it seems like you are willing to accept the possibility of dynamic failure.  Perhaps instead change `Foo` to not have the constraint but instead throw an exception when `T` is not a class type

Comment: Hi thanks for you answer.  I put the constraint on "Foo" because I wanted to use "Foo" to instantiate a new instance of the item.  So "Foo" on it's own really needs to take an object that can be instantiated by doing "new T()".  I'd rather have a runtime exception in "Bar" than "Foo".  But if reflection is the only option then I guess thats fine :)

Answer (score 0):

```
if (typeof(T).IsClass)
{
    this.GetType()
        .GetMethod("Foo", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance |
                          System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public)
        .Invoke(this, new object[] { item });
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure he explicitly asks if there is alternative to reflection.

Answer (score -1):

I believe there is no way to make it compile. You will have to use reflection to make the call.

Actually. You could cheat if you contain it within a class:

```
    public class Container<T>
    {
        public Container(T value)
        {
            Value = value;
        }

        public T Value { get; private set; }
    }

    public void Bar<T>(T item)
    {
        this.Foo<Container<T>>(new Container<T>(item));
    }
```

but this adds one layer you need to call-through and makes the types less clear.

Comment: This won't work because `Container<T>` doesn't match `Foo<T>(T item)` and if you will change it to: `Foo<T>(Container<T> item)` than it will still say that `T` must be a ref type.

Comment: he is saying that the line `new Container<T>(item)` won't compile because of the type constraint